# Chromium pop up on Raspbian

Tags: chromium, raspbian

I'm running Chromium 16 on a Raspberry Pi 3 with the latest Raspbian. My purpose is to launch a Chromium page in --kiosk mode on start-up.

The Pi will always be shut down by switching the power off, so on start-up Chromium shows the "Chromium didn't shut down properly" pop-up. I need to disable this pop-up. I already looked for a bunch of solutions on the web, especially on this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/873381/how-can-i-disable-the-chromium-didn-t-shut-down-correctly-message-when-my-brow

Sadly, none of these work for me. I also tried to set the permissions for the chromium preferences file to read only, but permissions seem to be restored on boot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a long time, here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set CrProfile to the value of your startup profile's config folder
CrProfile="Default"

HomeFolder="/home/myhome"

#Set URL to the URL that you want the browser to start with
URL="http://www.apple.com"

#Delete SingletonLock
rm -f $HomeFolder/.config/chromium/SingletonLock
rm -f $HomeFolder/.cache/chromium

#Clean up the randomly-named file(s)
for i in $HomeFolder/.config/chromium/$CrProfile/.org.chromium.Chromium.*; do
    sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly": true/' $i
    sed -i 's/"exit_state": "Crashed"/"exit_state": "Normal"/' $i
    sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' $i
done

#Clean up Preferences
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly": true/' $HomeFolder/.config/chromium/$CrProfile/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_state": "Crashed"/"exit_state": "Normal"/' $HomeFolder/.config/chromium/$CrProfile/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' $HomeFolder/.config/chromium/$CrProfile/Preferences

#Clean up Local State
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly": true/' $HomeFolder/.config/chromium/"Local State"

/usr/bin/X11/chromium-browser --no-first-run --kiosk $URL
```

Answer (score 1):

In most recent version (v60 here), I fix this by running with the following argument

```
chromium-browser --kiosk --app=http://www.example.com
```

Comment: This doesn't hide the popup for me anymore

Answer (score 0):

For those arriving here from Google:

The best way to now perform this task, without having to use incognito, is to adjust *two* settings in the Chromium preferences. They are:

- exited_cleanly
- exit_type

From what I have gathered from personal tests, just changing the "exited_cleanly" setting may not always work at preventing the Chromium prompt on startup. Other flags such as "-disable-infobars" will also not work.

To adjust these settings, please add the following in your startup file, before launching Chromium (depending on how you have set up Chromium to automatically run in kiosk mode, this file can either be located at "/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart", "/etc/xdg/openbox/autostart", "~/.Xsession", or another file, depending on what you have already installed).

- sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
- sed -i ‘s/”exit_type”: “Crashed”/”exit_type”: “Normal”/’ ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

For example, with my setup (using Xsession), the procedure would go as follows:

1. Enter "sudo ~/.Xsession" into the console
2. Insert the above 2 lines into the file, before Chromium is run (You should see a line starting with "chromium-browser", so insert them above this)
3. Press ctrl + X to exit the file
4. Type "Y"
5. Press enter
6. Reboot the machine

Again, the file used to start up Chromium may be located in a different location, depending on how you have setup your pi, but after changing these two settings, Chromium should start up without displaying the crashing prompt.